# Why doesn't the relativistic formula for momentum appear consistent with collisions?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, conservation-laws

The relativistic formula for momentum is
$$p = \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1 - \dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}} \,.$$

In the following example, I apply the formula in the most basic way possible to the addition of velocities. I calculate the momentum before the collision, $p_{0}$, and the momentum after the collision, $p_{1}$. Blindly using these formulas, I come to the conclusion that $p_{0} \neq p_{1}$. I suspect most beginning students of special relativity would not be able to find fault with this argument; it is therefore worth answering and of broad interest to the Stack Exchange community.

Consider two objects of mass $m$ initially at rest that, after some combustion, move apart from one another with velocity $v$ in the positive $x$ direction and negative $x$ direction. Move to the frame of reference that moves at velocity $v$ in the positive $x$ direction with respect to the initial position of the blocks at rest.

Before the collision, apparent velocity of the two objects joined at rest is $-v$. Therefore, \
$$p_{0} = -2\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1 - \dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}} \,.$$

After the collision, the object moving in the positive $x$ direction appears stationary with respect to the frame of reference. Applying the formula for the addition of velocities, the velocity of the object moving in the negative $x$ direction is,
$$v_{-} = \frac{-2v}{1 + \dfrac{v^2}{c^2}} \,.$$

Therefore, the total momentum of the system is
$$p_{1} = \frac{mv_{-}}{\sqrt{1 - \dfrac{v_{-}^2}{c^2}}} = -2\dfrac{mv}{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}} \,.$$

Thus, clearly, $p_{0} \neq p_{1}$.

Comment: Before you close this question, please give a carefully stated reason and explain clearly why you found this reasoning incorrect.

Comment: The resolution is that the rest mass $m$ of the reactants can change in relativistic collisions. For example, your example could have been describing the process $\mu^+ \mu^- \to e^+ e^-$ during which the parameter $m$ in your formulas changes from $m_\mu$ to $m_e$.

Comment: This is also a much better written question than your previous one! Thanks for improving it.

Comment: Ok—electrons are fine—but what about blocks? In Newtonian physics, we buy the idea that you can have two blocks at rest together. Then there's an "explosion" and they move apart with equal and opposite velocities. What's naive about this story to a relativity physicist?

Comment: This story must obey energy conservation, so the final energy must have come from somewhere -- in this case, from the internal energy of the objects before the collision. The new feature of relativity is that this energy, which was in the objects all along, contributes to their mass before collision via $E = mc^2$.

Comment: Indeed, a much better framing of the question. I've set you separate-line equations in the usual typesetting (use `$$ ... $$` for block set). as well as adding a few tags.

Comment: You seem to be saying there's no way to go from two blocks at rest to two blocks moving apart without destroying mass. Can't we use a conventional chemical combustion in which no mass is destroyed? Is there really no way with springs, etc.?

Comment: Mass *is* lost in conventional chemical explosives. It's just such a small fraction that you don't need to worry about it under most conditions. But if you are proposing to impart relativistic speeds to the two masses then you will need to keep track of it.

Comment: It might help to know that one of the ways to develop the expression for the relativistic momentum from first principles involves a computation on the behavior of a glancing, elastic collision. That makes your setup here interesting because it is an inelastic interaction, but that means keeping track of what happens to the energy as @knzhou says.

Comment: Before the explosion, can't we store energy in some way other than mass? Aren't there forms of energy other than mass—e.g., the potential energy of a coiled spring? Can't we attach a spring to each block and press the two springs together?

Comment: Yup, and the compressed spring will have more mass than when it's uncompressed!

Comment: Note that energy-momemtum make up a four-vector, and that mass is (to within the proper factors of $c$) the magnitude of that four-vector $(mc^2)^2 = E^2 - (\vec{p}c)^2$. Energy without momentum *is* mass and there is no way to dodge the result.

Comment: If you consider some sort of energy acting other than the 2 masses, which is in principle possible, you change the nature of the problem (even if conserving masses). In particular, the total energy of your system is different than just that due to the 2 masses (E+2m in the system rest frame, where E is the energy stored in your spring). Since momentum transformation is actually linear in energy and momentum, you end up mixing these quantities.

Comment: Ok—what about two *electrons* an angstrom apart. Initially at rest, they move away from one another by electromagnetic repulsion. Where's the lost mass?

Comment: The two electrons held at rest a distance $r$ from one another have more mass than $2m_e$ by $k e^2/ (r c^2)$ (i.e. the electric potential energy divided by $c^2$). You really *can't* dodge the extra energy thing. Instead, compute the momentum balance if you include that extra mass in the initial state.

Comment: All of the substance of this question was present in the earlier question.  The only differences between the two are:  1)  in the earlier version, the OP gave a specific example (with v=.6) while here he left $v$ unspecified.  This makes no difference to the quality of the question; in fact, the earlier version was probably a little easier to read.  And 2)  This time, people seem to have taken the trouble to read the question before voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the frame in which initially both the masses are at rest to be the frame $O$. In frame $O,$ momentum conservation is trivially followed because of the symmetry of the problem. For the energy conservation, we require that $M = m \sqrt{1-v^2}$, where $m$ is the initial rest mass of each of the particles and $M$ is the final rest mass of each of the particles.

Now, let's observe the situation from the point of view of an observer $O'$ moving with a velocity $v$ in the positive $x$ direction. In this frame, the initial momentum is

$$p_i = -\dfrac{2mv}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$

and the final momentum is

$$p_f = \dfrac{M\bigg(\dfrac{-2v}{1+v^2}\bigg)}{\sqrt{1-\bigg(\dfrac{-2v}{1+v^2}\bigg)^2}} = -\dfrac{2Mv}{1-v^2} = -\dfrac{2mv}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$
if $M=m\sqrt{1-v^2}$, which is consistent with what we derived from energy conservation in $O$.

For $O'$, the initial energy is

$$E_i = \dfrac{2m}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$

and the final energy is

$$E_f = \dfrac{M}{\sqrt{1-\bigg(\dfrac{-2v}{1+v^2}\bigg)^2}} + M = \dfrac{2M}{1-v^2} = \dfrac{2m}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$
for $M=m\sqrt{1-v^2}$, which is again consistent with all of the previous considerations.

So, taking into account the change in rest mass of the particles because of the change in their structure during combustion (or whatever process that accelerates them) we can see that in both the frames, both the energy and momentum conservation laws can be consistently maintained.